# Doctrine - Not equal to some value

Tags: mysql, select, doctrine-orm

I want to detect id that are not equal to *1,2,3* or NULL . here is my query:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u.cityId')
    ->from('.....\Entities\Cities', 'u')
    ->where("u.cityId is null OR u.cityId NOT IN (:parentType) ")
    ->setParameter('parentType' , "2,3,10");
$qb = $qb->getQuery();
return $qb->getResult();
```

Although it shows me *id* which are NULL or not equal to 2 and another values. It's not restrict 3,10. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array. Try this:

```
->setParameter('parentType' , array(2,3,10) );
```

Instead of:

```
->setParameter('parentType' , "2,3,10");
```

Hope this help